# How to detect only combination of numbers and letters by regex

Tags: regex

I need to detect only the word from a sentence where only combination of the numbers and letters exists by regex.

I am using this https://regex101.com/r/eSlu2I/1 `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*` regex.

Here last two ones should be excluded.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Edit your question to include examples of words that should match and others that should not match. Also define what "word" means, eg is "top-notch" one word or two words? You mention nothing about only matching the *first* word, but your regex has the start of input anchor `^` - please confirm that you only want to match the leading characters or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
\w*\d\w*
```

Explanation:

- `\w*`: optional combination of alphanumeric characters
- `\d`: digit
- `\w*`: optional combination of alphanumeric characters

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/1JySZk/1).

---

**EDIT**: In case you require the presence of at least one letter together with the number, you can instead use the following regex:

```
\w*(\d[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]\d)\w*
```

Explanation:

- `\w*`: optional combination of alphanumeric characters
- `(\d[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]\d)`:

  - `\d[A-Za-z]|`: digit + alphabetical character or
  - `[A-Za-z]\d`: alphabetical character + digit
- `\w*`: optional combination of alphanumeric characters

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
^(?![a-zA-Z]+\b)[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/ooW3rV/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z0-9]*             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                           '0' to '9' (0 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
```